# How to chain isearch-forward-symbol-at-point and query-replace-regexp into a single keybinding?

Tags: key-bindings, regular-expressions, isearch

I'm looking to create a keybinding that will perform the following shortcut:

- call `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`
- call `query-replace-regexp`

It's basically a shortcut for the following key combo: `M-s .` then `C-M $`

Here is my attempt, but my elisp is rather weak:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r")
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (query-replace-regexp (isearch-forward-symbol-at-point))))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may be interested in looking at [iedit](https://melpa.org/#/iedit) (on MELPA).

Answer (score 1):

This is the key binding that does what you want, out of the box: `M-s . C-M-%`.

- The `M-s .` part starts searching with `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`.
- The `C-M-%` part starts `query-replace-regexp`, the current search string as the old text, to search for and replace.

(`C-M-$` is undefined in `isearch-mode-map` (and the global map).)

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to make that key binding shorter? I basically want a single key combo that I can push to perform a "refactor the variable under my cursor".

Comment: As @Tobias said in his answer, these commands are for interactive use - they don't chain together programmatically. But you can do as he did: set up the regexp for replacement and then call `query-replace-regexp`. You are not really searching for the symbol at point - you are using it just to establish the regexp to use for replacement. Alternatively, you could perhaps define a keyboard macro using the two commands directly (possibly with recursive editing). But it's easier to just do it in Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

You should/cannot use the interactive commands `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` and `query-replace-regexp` in that way to define a new function.

For an instance `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` does not return the symbol at point and `query-replace-regexp` requires a TO argument if called non-interactively.

I think the following Elisp function comes very close to what you want. It starts a `query-replace-regexp` with the symbol at point as default regexp. You only need to input the replacement text, i.e., the new name.

```el
(defun query-replace-symbol-at-point ()
  "Start `query-replace-regexp' with symbol at point as default."
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (symbol-at-point)))
    (when sym
      (push (cons (format "\\_<%s\\_>" sym) "") query-replace-defaults)
      (call-interactively #'query-replace-regexp))))
```